# Getting older balances of credit and debit accounts from transactions table for users in bulk

Tags: mysql, group-by, aggregate

```
CREATE TABLE `account` (
  `id` bigint(15) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `account_id` bigint(14) NOT NULL,
  `acc_complete_id` bigint(14) DEFAULT NULL,
  `uuid` varchar(400) NOT NULL,
  `last_updated` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `balance` decimal(19,2) DEFAULT '0.00'
)
```

Transaction

```
CREATE TABLE `transaction` (
  `id` bigint(19) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `amount` decimal(19,2) DEFAULT '0.00',
  `debit` bigint(14) DEFAULT NULL,
  `credit` bigint(14) DEFAULT NULL,
  `credit_bal` decimal(19,2) DEFAULT '0.00',
  `debit_bal` decimal(19,2) DEFAULT '0.00'
 )
```

- Id field in account table padded with 1 and a set of zeroes is the debit column of transaction table. Similarly for credit.
- Transaction table maintains debit and credit entries of users involved in a txn.
- Latest user balance is stored in account.balance.
- Balances of users at the end of each txn are there in debit_bal and credit_bal.

Now, we need to find the older balances of a bulk of users in the system.

For this, we are trying to get the latest debit balances and latest credit balances for each user -

However, this is not ordering the created dates for each uuid, but in the final result set, hence not making sense -

```
SELECT pa.uuid
     , pt.debit_bal
     , pt.created 
  FROM consumer.account pa force index (account_id_UNIQUE) 
  JOIN consumer.transaction pt 
    ON pa.account_id+ 100000000000 = pt.debit 
 GROUP 
    BY pa.uuid 
 ORDER 
    BY pt.created desc;
```

Some sample data -

Account table -

```
+------+------------+-----------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------+
| id   | account_id | acc_complete_id | uuid                | last_updated        | created             | balance |
+------+------------+-----------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------+
|   29 |      50536 |    100000050536 | 1026651502611722400 | 2020-01-09 12:43:49 | 2018-01-01 00:00:01 | 2092.10 |
| 1337 |      53071 |    100000053071 | 7266704751953077361 | 2019-12-26 11:45:54 | 2019-10-22 18:13:21 |   99.00 |
|   30 |      50673 |    100000050673 | 8799857402485889540 | 2020-01-05 13:21:16 | 2017-01-01 00:00:01 | 2166.10 |
+------+------------+-----------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------+
```

Transaction

```
+---------+---------------------+--------+--------------+--------------+-----------+------------+
| id      | created             | amount | debit        | credit       | debit_bal | credit_bal |
+---------+---------------------+--------+--------------+--------------+-----------+------------+
| 2001705 | 2019-12-07 14:14:18 |   1.00 | 100000050536 |            3 |   2092.00 | 2332445.91 |
| 2001869 | 2020-05-08 14:29:00 |   4.00 | 100000050673 | 200000052870 |   2088.10 |       4.00 |
| 2001874 | 2020-05-09 14:45:04 |   4.00 | 100000050673 | 200000052870 |   2084.10 |       8.00 |
| 2001875 | 2020-05-09 14:46:37 |   4.00 | 100000050673 | 200000052870 |   2080.10 |      12.00 |
| 2002018 | 2019-11-29 18:05:41 |  50.00 | 100000053071 | 300000050673 |      0.00 |    2170.10 |
| 2002019 | 2019-11-29 18:07:41 |   1.00 | 100000053071 | 300000050673 |    100.00 |    2170.10 |
| 2002020 | 2019-11-29 18:07:56 |   1.00 | 100000053071 |            5 |    100.00 |  580037.00 |
| 2002021 | 2019-11-29 18:15:22 |   1.00 | 100000053071 |            5 |    100.00 |  580037.00 |
| 2002022 | 2019-11-29 18:18:45 |   1.00 | 100000053071 |            5 |    100.00 |  580037.00 |
| 2002023 | 2019-11-29 18:20:41 |   1.00 | 100000053071 |            5 |    100.00 |  580037.00 |
| 2002024 | 2019-11-29 18:24:18 |   1.00 | 100000053071 |            5 |    100.00 |  580037.00 |
| 2002025 | 2019-11-29 18:26:19 |   1.00 | 100000053071 |            5 |    100.00 |  580037.00 |
| 2002026 | 2019-11-29 18:28:41 |   1.00 | 100000053071 |            5 |    100.00 |  580037.00 |
| 2002027 | 2019-11-29 18:29:37 |   1.00 | 100000053071 |            5 |    100.00 |  580037.00 |
| 2002028 | 2019-11-29 18:30:40 |   1.00 | 100000053071 |            5 |    100.00 |  580037.00 |
| 2002029 | 2019-11-29 18:35:55 |   1.00 | 100000053071 |            5 |    100.00 |  580037.00 |
| 2002030 | 2019-11-29 18:42:16 |   1.00 | 100000053071 |            5 |    100.00 |  580037.00 |
| 2002031 | 2019-12-02 13:12:01 |   1.00 | 100000053071 |            5 |    100.00 |  580037.00 |
| 2002032 | 2019-12-02 13:18:21 |   1.00 | 100000053071 |            5 |    100.00 |  580037.00 |
| 2002033 | 2019-12-02 13:27:53 |   1.00 | 100000053071 |            5 |    100.00 |  580037.00 |
| 2002034 | 2019-12-02 13:38:11 |   1.00 | 100000053071 |            5 |     99.00 |  580038.00 |
+---------+---------------------+--------+--------------+--------------+-----------+------------+
```

Note - Unable to export into csv file, because I am stuck with ERROR 1290 (HY000): The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement

Results I am getting is -

```
SELECT pa.uuid
     , pt.debit_bal
     , pt.created 
  FROM consumer.account pa force index (account_id_UNIQUE) 
  JOIN consumer.transaction pt 
    ON pa.account_id+ 100000000000 = pt.debit 
 GROUP 
    BY pa.uuid 
 ORDER 
    BY pt.created DESC;
+---------------------+-----------+---------------------+
| uuid                | debit_bal | created             |
+---------------------+-----------+---------------------+
| 8799857402485889540 |   2088.10 | 2020-05-08 14:29:00 |
| 1026651502611722400 |   2092.00 | 2019-12-07 14:14:18 |
| 7266704751953077361 |      0.00 | 2019-11-29 18:05:41 |
+---------------------+-----------+---------------------+
```

For user 8799857402485889540, 2088.10  is not the latest balance. Actually,  2080.10 is. This query is not ordering by the created dates for each uuid, but rather from the final result set of all users, hence not making sense.

**Update**

tried with this as well -

```
 SELECT pa.uuid, 
       pt.debit_bal, 
       Max(pt.created) 
FROM   consumer.account pa FORCE INDEX (account_id_unique) 
       JOIN consumer.transaction pt 
         ON ( pa.account_id + 100000000000 ) = pt.debit 
GROUP  BY pa.uuid;
```

It returns the latest txn date, but does not return associated debit_bal.

```
   +---------------------+-----------+---------------------+
| uuid                | debit_bal | max(pt.created)     |
+---------------------+-----------+---------------------+
| 1026651502611722400 |   2092.00 | 2019-12-07 14:14:18 |
| 7266704751953077361 |      0.00 | 2019-12-02 13:38:11 |
| 8799857402485889540 |   2088.10 | 2020-05-09 14:46:37 |
+---------------------+-----------+---------------------+
```

Comment: Note that DISTINCT is not a function, and is rarely, if ever, used in conjunction with a GROUP BY clause (except as a modifier to an aggregate function)

Comment: For further help, see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Finally, note that in the absence of any aggregating functions, a GROUP BY clause is NEVER appropriate.

Comment: @Strawberry added aggregate in a update.

Answer (score 0):

I should say that the data is poorly organised. Better to re-design with your requirements in mind. Anyway going by the data...

distinct(pa.uuid) combined along with other columns in select query would result in taking a row from same uuid and then assembling other columns based on the conditions given which is **not at all expected**

Instead just take pa.uuid and other required columns and can add max(credited) as a criteria.

**Edit 1:**

You are grouping which would arrange rows and arriving at unwanted row. Try this.

```
select pa.uuid, pt.debit_bal, pt.created
from consumer.account pa join...on...
where pt.created= 
  (select max(pt1.created) from consumer.transaction pt1 
    where pt1.uuid= pa.uuid)
```

Comment: Checked the answer?